# Is there a protocol like SPI that supports multiple MISO and MOSI channels?

Tags: spi, communication, dma

I need to implement a driver that uses clock-data protocol within the data link layer. It's just like SPI but with multiple MOSI and MISO channels. Is there any pre-defined protocol like that? (DMA will be used if there is no such pre-defined protocol)

Comment: dual, quad and octal spi are common on newer microcontrollers. Is this what you're wanting? Serial flash/ram use these variants.

Comment: I think the ask is for multiple streams of MISO and MOSI on the same clock. That’s a bit different. Some MCUs (like i.MX8) support modes like this.

Comment: @hacktastical, that's what I was referring to - clock and 1,2,4 or 8 data bits. The ESP32 I2S peripheral will do up to 16 bits and clock

Comment: As far as I know there aren't any.

Comment: @Kartman I'm not looking for multiple SPI peripherals, I'm looking for single clock and multiple MOSI/MISO channels, as hacktastical says.

Comment: That’s exactly what i’ve suggested. For quad spi (qspi) four bits are transferred on each clock. Something like the STM32H7xx has up to octal spi - 8 bits are transferred on each clock.

Comment: @Kartman I thought you were talking about 4 different SPI peripherals. Now I searched for "qspi" and I got what you mean. I'll accept if you post it as an answer.